# How to create multiple columns from one column using values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I have a dataset of time-series data with almost 100 stores. Time period is couple of years (but not for all stores - there are some older and newer ones).

| Store_num | date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 01Jan2012 | 125 |
| 23 | 01Feb2012 | 12 |
| 23 | 01Mar2012 | 388 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 57 | 01Jan2013 | 456 |
| 57 | 01Feb2013 | 555 |
| 57 | 01Mar2013 | 545 |
| 57 | 01Apr2013 | 657 |
| ... | ... | ... |

To perform predictions of future sales (first approach with statsmodels) I decided to change that df to:

| date | 23_sales | 57_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01Jan2012 | 125 | NaN |
| 01Feb2012 | 12 | NaN |
| 01Mar2012 | 388 | NaN |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 01Jan2013 | ... | 456 |
| 01Feb2013 | ... | 555 |
| 01Mar2013 | ... | 545 |
| 01Apr2013 | ... | 657 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I am able to add those columns one by one but I fail with creating some kind of loop.
My approach for doing it one by one:

```
store_23 = df[df['Store_num'] == 23].copy()
store_23.set_index(store_23['date'], inplace = True)
store_23.drop(['Store', 'date'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
store_23.columns = ['23_sales']
```

I was thinking also of creating a list of sales names (column names):

```
df_list = df['Store_num'].unique()
y_list = [str(num) + "_y" for num in df_list]
```

and than creating new df and adding data using groupby but I also failed in this approach.

Can anyone give me some suggestions ? Maybe my approach is completly wrong ?

Comment: Format date column using pandas to `datetime`  format properly. @Tom Also, what you are looking for is called `unstack`

Comment: When I was making those tables I was looking at the original df, that's why I wrote dates before formating ... my mistake. Method df.unstack looks similar to .pivot maybe it can be done both ways but .pivot worked for me! Thanks for Your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iiuc you want df.pivot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'store_num':[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
        'date':[1,2,3]*3,
        'sales':np.random.randint(0,10,9),
    }
)

df.pivot(index='date', columns='store_num')
```

Comment: It worked like a charm ! I was looking for the solution on so many different ways but I haven't  found .pivot. Thanks for Your help !